# How do you allocate space well for multiple arrays in Y86 assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, y86

I am trying to convert C code into Y86 assembly code.

What happens if you have multiple array declarations such as:

```
int a[100], b[100];
```

Suppose every integer is 4 bytes. How do you know where in memory to point for the pos. directives so that you do not waste any space?

```
<Assembly code begins here>

...

halt

# Array initialization begins here
.pos ?
A:
.long 0

.pos ?   
B:
.long 0
```

Comment: You use the stack. Not fixed memory locations. All it is is simple arithmetic

Comment: Hmm ok, does this mean I will just have to keep track of the memory positions of the beginning of each array? Like suppose I knew the starting positions for my two arrays were at 0 and 400, would I have to treat everything as displacement from the stack pointer?

Comment: Also: Suppose I had 10 arrays. Would I have to keep track of each array's starting memory position as a displacement from the stack pointer? Or is there a better way to do it? Because wouldn't it get confusing with all the hard coding of displacement values?

Comment: The compiler keeps an internal tab on them. If you are writing it yourself, you need to take a step back and read up on this stuff first.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could just give me a straight answer. If you were just writing it yourself, then you would have to keep track of the displacements yourself. But the compiler has its own way of keeping track of displacements. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. It does. To keep track of it yourself, you would use MASM's `EQU`, NASM's `eq`, etc. As for a strait answer, I'm not familiar in Y86, only x86, so I can only give pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the assembler worry about the offsets.
One possibility is to define a struct that contains local variables

```
struc Locals
    a dd ? dup 100
    b dd ? dup 100
ends Locals

sub esp, sizeof Locals ;; or perhaps sizeof struc Locals
mov ebp, esp           ;; take a copy of stack ptr

mov eax, [ebp + offset a] ;;  
mov ebx, [ebp + offset b] ;;
```

In gcc the meaning of 'struct' is to modify the absolute position of current segment without introducing linkable code:

```
.file "temp.c"
    .struct 0
a:  .struct a + 4*100
b:  .struct b + 4*100
c:               ;; c will contain expression for the size
    .struct 0    ;; you can start a new struct here
a2: .struct a2 + 4   ;; this struct would be  'int a2;'
b2: .struct b2 + 8   ;;  'double b2'
c2:                  ;; sizeof struct #2

.text  
    sub c, %rsp
    mov $13, a(%rsp)   ;; a[0] = 13
    mov $2,  b(%rsp)   ;; b[0] = 2
```